# Hough circle always return none

Tags: python, opencv, hough-transform

I am detecting pupils in my current project. I planned to use hough circle detection. It works well with the image but it is tricky in real time video frame.

I found one answer in stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31140386/python-opencv-hough-circles-returns-none), but it is not for video and not explained.

```
import cv2
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.ndimage import imread
import numpy as np

fgbg = cv2.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG()
cam_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
upper_left = (50, 50)
bottom_right = (300, 300)

def sketch_transform(image)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = 255-gray
    ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 225, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, 
                         cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    image = cv2.drawContours(image, contours, -1,(0,0,255),3)
    circle_detect(image)
    return image

def circle_detect(image):
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(image,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,
                            param1=90,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=100)
    print(circles)
    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
    for i in circles[0,:]:
        # draw the outer circle
        cv2.circle(image,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
        # draw the center of the circle
        cv2.circle(image,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)
    return image

while True:
    _, image_frame = cam_capture.read()
    r = cv2.rectangle(image_frame, upper_left, bottom_right, (100, 50, 
    200), 5)
    rect_img = image_frame[upper_left[1] : bottom_right[1], upper_left[0] 
                                   : bottom_right[0]]
    sketcher_rect = rect_img
    sketcher_rect = sketch_transform(sketcher_rect)
    sketcher_rect_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(sketcher_rect, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
    image_frame[upper_left[1] : bottom_right[1], upper_left[0] 
    bottom_right[0]] = sketcher_rect_rgb
    cv2.imshow("Sketcher ROI", image_frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 13:
        break        
cam_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

the output of my program is:

```
None Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py",
line 51, in _wrapfunc
    return getattr(obj, method)(*args, **kwds) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'round'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/home/pi/Downloads/Pi-tracker-master/fgroi.py", line 49, in <module>
    sketcher_rect = sketch_transform(sketcher_rect)   File "/home/pi/Downloads/Pi-tracker-master/fgroi.py", line 20, in
sketch_transform
    ...
    result = getattr(asarray(obj), method)(*args, **kwds) AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rint
```